# how to integrate sentencepiece, protobuf into existing android project correctly

Tags: android, cmake, protobuf-java, sentencepiece

I am trying to integrate pytorch model to process language. This is why I need the sentencepiece to tokenize the sentence chunks. But I am unable to do that correctly.

I did not find any robust documentation of integrating sentencepiece into android app. The way I tried is.

- **I copied the source code(https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) to android app like the we do CPP files. now the problem is , there is throwing some error with protobuf.**

  **CMake Error at C:/Users/Reve/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Reve/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/Reve/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:626 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:106 (find_package)**

[image]

Now can anyone please tell me how to solve this error or can anyone give me the guidance to integrate the sentencepiece into the android apps correctly...